# PHPUnit: Mocking Symfony2 FormBuilderInterface - type hinting issues

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I am trying to test a class that extends `Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType`, and having trouble testing the required `buildForm` method with a PHPUnit mock object:

```
class PageType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text');
    }

    // ...
 }
```

Here's some example test code:

```
public function testBuildForm()
{
    $form = new PageType($this->manager);
    $formBuilder = $this->getMock('Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface');
    $form->buildForm($formBuilder, array());
}
```

Unfortunately the call to `getMock()` fails:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class Mock_FormBuilderInterface_f36f83d4 must implement interface Traversable as part of either Iterator or IteratorAggregate in Unknown on line 0
```

I suspect I might have fallen foul of this bug:
https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/604

So, I have created an interface to work around the problem:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

interface FormBuilderInterfaceExtender extends \Iterator, FormBuilderInterface
{
}
```

and changed my test code:

```
public function testBuildForm()
{
    $form = new PageType($this->manager);
    $formBuilder = $this->getMock('Pwn\ContentBundle\Tests\Helper\FormBuilderInterfaceExtender');
    $form->buildForm($formBuilder, array());
}
```

Now I have a FormBuilder instance, but PHP doesn't see it as an instance of `Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface`, so the type hinting in `$form->buildForm()` gives this error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Pwn\ContentBundle\Form\Type\PageType::buildForm() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface, instance of Mock_FormBuilderInterfaceExtender_3527f313 given
```

In other cases when I've used a mock object, type hinting and `instanceof` work correctly, but here it doesn't:

```
var_dump($formBuilder);
var_dump($formBuilder instanceof \Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface);
```

gives

```
class Mock_FormBuilderInterfaceExtender_76df04af#19 (1) {
  private $__phpunit_invocationMocker =>
  NULL
}
bool(false)
```

It seems I *can* make this work by mocking a class that implements the interface:

```
$formBuilder = $this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder')
                    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                    ->getMock();

var_dump($formBuilder instanceof \Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface);
// ^ gives bool(true)
```

However, should I be able to use the interface itself? Why does extending an interface 'lose' the type hinting?

Comment: Have you tried `assertInstanceOf` instead of `instanceof`?  Have a peak at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250503/phpunit-mocked-interfaces-and-instanceof).

Comment: Just tried it, but assertInstanceOf is just a convenient way of using instanceof, so the effect is the same.

Comment: Thought there might have been some magic in there (you never know w/ phpUnit)!  I put together a litmus test (see answer below) and seems like this should work so probably something subtle.

Comment: Have you tried `getMock('Symfony\Component\Form\Tests\FormBuilderInterface')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you can't test a Symfony2 interface, look in the component's Tests directory to see if there is a mock specifically for testing.  The test interfaces extend the real interface, and add any tweaks required to make phpunit run them.

In your case, try mocking `Symfony\Component\Form\Tests\FormBuilderInterface` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it, I'll look out for those test classes if I run into something like this again.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like PHPUnit can Mock interfaces just fine, and has no problem with interfaces that extend other interfaces.  Take a look at this class & TestCase

**NamespaceA.php**

```
<?php
namespace Testing;
interface NamespaceA {}
```

**TestMockInterfaces.php**

```
<?php
require 'NamespaceA.php';

interface Custom extends Testing\NamespaceA, Iterator, ArrayAccess {}

class TestMockInterfaces extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testMocks()
    {
        $oSolidMock = $this->getMock('Iterator');
        $this->assertTrue($oSolidMock instanceof Iterator);

        $oSketchyMock = $this->getMock('Custom');
        $this->assertTrue($oSketchyMock instanceof Iterator);
        $this->assertTrue($oSketchyMock instanceof ArrayAccess);
        $this->assertTrue($oSketchyMock instanceof \Testing\NamespaceA);
    }
}
```

This passes 100%, so I suspect there's something else going on.

After you mock `FormBuilderInterfaceExtender` try `var_dump(class_implements($formBuilder));` and see if it's what you expect.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful... although Adrian's answer solved the actual problem, I hadn't come across class_implements before; this made it much easier to see what was going on.

Comment: Well, you should try to mock an interface that extends Traversable.