# Can I mock an interface implementation with PHPUnit?

Tags: php, interface, mocking, phpunit

I've got an interface I'd like to mock. I know I can mock an implementation of that interface, but is there a way to just mock the interface?

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use My\Http\IClient as IHttpClient;  // The interface
use My\SomethingElse\Client as SomethingElseClient;


class SomethingElseClientTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
  public function testPost() {
    $url = 'some_url';
    $http_client = $this->getMockBuilder('Cpm\Http\IClient');
    $something_else = new SomethingElseClient($http_client, $url);
  }
}
```

What I get here is:

```
1) SomethingElseTest::testPost
Argument 1 passed to Cpm\SomethingElse\Client::__construct() must be an instance of
My\Http\IClient, instance of PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockBuilder given, called in
$PATH_TO_PHP_TEST_FILE on line $NUMBER and defined
```

Interestingly, [PHPUnit, mocked interfaces, and instanceof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250503/phpunit-mocked-interfaces-and-instanceof) would suggest this might work.

Comment: You have misread that other question, it is using `->getMock()` not `->getMockBuilder()` as you do - and that is as you found out the answer to your problem as well. However IIRC a duplicate of your question here does exist as well but I can't find it right now.

Comment: Interesting. I couldn't find it in my search. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: you can also accept your answer below so that your question is marked answered.

Comment: Good call. Doesn't seem like there's more input to be made here. Thank you.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Instead of

```
$http_client = $this->getMockBuilder(Cpm\Http\IClient::class);
```

use

```
$http_client = $this->getMock(Cpm\Http\IClient::class);
```

or

```
$http_client = $this->getMockBuilder(Cpm\Http\IClient::class)->getMock();
```

Totally works!

Comment: I had to $mockBuilder->setMethods(['all','my','interface','methods']) to get it to work. But yeah, works perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: only $this->getMockBuilder(...)->getMock() worked for me

PHPUnit 7.5.1

Comment: `$this->getMock` no long exists since PHPUnit 6 https://stackoverflow.com/a/42762123/1462295

Answer (score 20):

The following works for me:

```
$myMockObj = $this->createMock(MyInterface::class);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$http_client = $this->getMockBuilder(Cpm\Http\IClient::class)
                    ->setMockClassName('SomeClassName')
                    ->getMock();
```

The *setMockClassName()* can be used to fix this in some circumstances.