# Error: Call to undefined method DateFormatterTest::getMock()

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

**Update:** with `$stub = $this->createMock('Config');` this example works, but I get a warning:

> OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests! Tests: 1, Assertions: 0,
>   Risky: 1.

In the video-tutorial this example works without any warnings. Is it possible to fix this warning?

---

I can't find why I am getting this error and how to fix it. This code is from a video tutorial. And in the Video it works. Maybe a typo?

**Error:**

> c:\laragon\www\phpunit λ phpunit --colors tests\DateFormatterTest.php
>   PHPUnit 6.0.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> E                                                                   1
>   / 1 (100%)
>
> Time: 35 ms, Memory: 4.00MB
>
> There was 1 error:
>
> 1) DateFormatterTest::testFormattingDatesBasedOnConfig Error: Call to
>   undefined method DateFormatterTest::getMock()
>
> C:\laragon\www\phpunit\tests\DateFormatterTest.php:10
>
> ERRORS! Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.

Here my code:

**Config.php**

```
<?php

class Config {
    public function get() {
        return 'd-m-Y';
    }
}
```

**DateFormatter.php**

class DateFormatter {
    protected $config;

```
public function __construct (Config $config) {
    $this->config = $config;
}

public function getFormattedDate($timestamp) {
    return date($this->config->get('date.format'), $timestamp);
}
```

}

**DateFormatterTest.php**

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

require_once 'C:\laragon\www\phpunit\src\DateFormatter.php';
require_once 'C:\laragon\www\phpunit\src\Config.php';

class DateFormatterTest extends TestCase {
    public function testFormattingDatesBasedOnConfig() {
        $stub = $this->getMock('Config');

        var_dump($stub);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`getMock()` no longer exists in PHPUnit 6. Use `createMock()` or `getMockBuilder()` instead.

Comment: Thank you for fast answer! With createMock I get: `OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests! Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Risky: 1.`. Why is this a _risky_ test? In the video this test works without any warnings.

Comment: @MeteorNewbie : If you execute exactly the same code as shown in your question, your test does not test anything ! So, it is considered as risky.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!