# Error: Call to undefined method Tests\Unit\ReportTest::getMock()

Tags: phpunit

I'm trying to test any public methods run as expected with mock objects (including mocking PDO). I'm running PHPUnit `"phpunit/phpunit": ">=9.6.8"` for all intents and purposes. Here goes:-

**Tests/Unit/ReportTest.php**

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Tests\Unit;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class ReportTest extends TestCase
{

    public function testReport(): void
    {
        $query = $this->getMock(\PDOStatement::class);
        $query->expects($this->once())
            ->method('execute');

        $db = $this->getMockBuilder(\PDO::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(['prepare'])
            ->getMock();

        $db->expects($this->once())
            ->method('prepare')
            ->willReturn($query);

        $report = new \Models\Report($db);
        $report->getReport('testSlug');

//        $this->assertFalse($report->getReport('testSlug'));
        $this->expectException(\PDOException::class);

    }
}
```

**Models/Report.php**

```
namespace Models;

use PDO;
use PDOException;
use Exception;

class Report
{
    private $dbh;


    public function __construct(PDO $pdo)
    {
        $this->dbh = $pdo;
        $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

    /**
     * Prepares and returns a report for the front-end
     * @param array $params
     * @return array|false
     */
    public function getReport($slug)
    {
        $sql = $this->getQuery($slug);

        if (!$sql) {
            throw new PDOException("Unable to find report");
        }

        return $sql;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the SQL for a report
     * @param $slug
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function getQuery(string $slug)
    {
        $query = "select query_sql from reports WHERE slug=:slug limit 1";
        $statement = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue(':slug', $slug, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();

        return $statement->fetchColumn();
    }

}
```

Upon running `docker compose --profile tools run phpunit`  I get: `Error: Call to undefined method Tests\Unit\ReportTest::getMock()` I get similar results if I replace with `createMock()` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42762098/error-call-to-undefined-method-dateformattertestgetmock Note the answer is given by the developer of PHPUnit.

Comment: not really, no. Using `createMock()` instead, i receive: `Error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\MockBuilder::createMock()`

Comment: I tested your code with PHPUnit 10.1.3, and I did not get that error. I changed the deprecated `getMock()` to `createMock()` and I changed the deprecated `setMethods()` to `onlyMethods()` and then it worked. I think you need to study the current documentation and examples matching the version of PHPUnit you are using.

Comment: I think you need to replace 
`$query = $this->getMock(\PDOStatement::class);`
for 
`$query = $this->createMock(\PDOStatement::class);` 

as the TestCase doesnt have a method getMock() this is defined on a MockBuilderClass

Answer (score 0):

The following test managed to run successfully:-

```
public function testReport(): void
{
       
    $query = $this->createMock(\PDOStatement::class);
    $query->expects($this->once())
        ->method('execute');

    $db = $this->getMockBuilder(\PDO::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->onlyMethods(['prepare', 'setAttribute'])
            ->getMock();

    $db->expects($this->once())
            ->method('prepare')
            ->willReturn($query);

    $report = new Report($db);

    $this->expectException(\PDOException::class);
    $report->getReport('testSlug');
}
```