# Make the return value a new function

Tags: php, function, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I've encountered this issue a few times now in my task to add unittests to the project, the issue is that I need to return a function as return value (and cant change the class itself). Small example:

```
// The code has a:
$thing->doFoo()->getBar();

// So I start the mock:
$thingMock = $this->createMock(Thing::class);
$thingMock->method('doFoo')->willReturn(/* WHAT DO I WRITE HERE? */);
```

---

Then part two of the issue, I want to make a helperfunction where I can define the result of `getBar`:

```
private function createThingMock($example){
    $thingMock = $this->createMock(Thing::class);
    $thingMock->method('doFoo')->willReturn(/* WHAT HERE? I must return $example */);
}
```

---

I currently have the following, but it's very bulky after a code format:

```
private function createThingMock($example){
    $thingMock = $this->createMock(Thing::class);
    $thingMock->method('doFoo')->willReturn(
        new class($options)
        {
            private $options;
            public function __construct($options) {
                $this->options = $options;
            }

           public function getBar(): string
            {
                return $example ?? 'currently $example is always null';
            }
        }
    );
}
```

That is the result after a code format and as you can see it's very bulky for something that feels it could be done a lot more simple. Suggestions?

Comment: `$thing->doFoo()` must return an object of a specific type (at least from inheritance point of view), so should that return a mock of the returned class which can then implement the `getBar()` method?

Comment: The current issue which is blocking me is a class I can't simply mock (I believe it's final or abstract). I just need it to return a string, I dont need the original function (so I'm somewhat lucky).

Answer (score 0):

*I'm not sure to understand your problem, so excuse me if I answer off the mark.*

I assume that `Thing::doFoo()` is returning an instance of class named SubThing.
I assume that class `SubThing` has a method named doBar() returning a string

```
// The code has a:
$thing->doFoo()->getBar();

// So I start the mock:
$subThingMock = $this->createMock(SubThing::class);
$subThingMock->method('doBar')->willReturn('sample string');

$thingMock = $this->createMock(Thing::class);
$thingMock->method('doFoo')->willReturn($subThingMock);
```

If `SubThing` is an implementation of interface named `ThingInterface`, [mock your interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250503/phpunit-mocked-interfaces-and-instanceof):

```
// So I start by mocking interface:
$subThingMock = $this->createMock(ThingInterface::class);
$subThingMock->method('doBar')->willReturn('sample string');

$thingMock = $this->createMock(Thing::class);
$thingMock->method('doFoo')->willReturn($subThingMock);
```

If `SubThing` is an instance of a subclass of abstract class `AbstractThing`, [you can mock it too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190295/testing-abstract-classes):

```
$subThingMock = $this->getMockForAbstractClass(AbstractThing::class);
$subThingMock->method('doBar')->willReturn('sample string');

$thingMock = $this->createMock(Thing::class);
$thingMock->method('doFoo')->willReturn($subThingMock);
```

In any case, if you only want to return a string, you can create a substitution class:

```
class Substitution {
   public function doBar(){
     return 'sample string';
   }
}

$subThing = new Substitution();

$thingMock = $this->createMock(Thing::class);
$thingMock->method('doFoo')->willReturn($subThing); //$subThing, not $subThingMock
```